# SpringBoot H2 db shows no records

Tags: java, sql

I connect database in intellij idea ultimate with my project, after clicking on schema I get nothing even I use POST method with postman.

I'm using flywaydb and I created migrations.

This is my problem:
[image: Table with no rows]

I should get some records after postman

App properties:
[image: App properties]

Datasource
[image: Datasource]

Comment: Can you show us your POST method in the related controller please?

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

one problem might be the data you are posting is not being posted.

Try the following

1. your post controller is actually posting data to the db
2. expose a get endpoint and try to fetch your data from the browser
3. If the two work then you can check on the db issues otherwise you might not have created any db just yet